# Move contents of folder up one level

Tags: windows-10, batch, file-management

I'm trying to move all files that are in a level-three sub-directory structure up one level.

`A:\mozartBilder\Box 03 - Divertimenti, Serenades\CD02\img\folder.jpg`

I basically want to get rid of the `img` sub-directory, but keep its contents one level above.

These are of my 180 cd collection of Mozart's Works. There are 180 cds, 17 Box Sets, each box containing ~11 cds.
Each picture was placed in this exact structure:

`A:\mozartBilder\Box*number1-17\CD*1-11\img\folder.jpg`

What I want to achive is that the `folder.jpg` gets moved up one directory.

So to go from

`A:\mozartBilder\Box 03 - Divertimenti, Serenades\CD02\img\folder.jpg`

to

`A:\mozartBilder\Box 03 - Divertimenti, Serenades\CD02\folder.jpg`

I've searched on SuperUser and found people with similar questions, however none of the provided solutions worked for me.

For this code:

`A:\mozartBilder>for /r %i in ("img\folder.jpg") do move %i %~pi..`

I get this error:

`A:\mozartBilder>move A:\mozartBilder\Box 02 - Serenades, Dances, Marches\CD03\"img\folder.jpg" \mozartBilder\Box 02 - Serenades, Dances, Marches\CD03\"img\..
The syntax of the command is incorrect.`

Comment: Are there any folder.jpg files in the 'box-level" folders or does the following PowerShell list _only_ the files you want to move: `gci A:\mozartBilder folder.jpg -recurse | select fullname`

Comment: No, in "box-level" folder there are no folder.jpg files. they are located in ..\img\ I ran this powershell command and it provides a list of all the files located in ..\img. But now, how can I move them so they all sit one level above? `A:\mozartBilder\BOX***\CD01\img\folder.jpg --> A:\mozartBilder\BOX***\CD01\folder.jpg`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To move folder.jpg up one level but keep the \img folder:

```
gci A:\mozartBilder folder.jpg -recurse |
   move-item -Destination {$_.Directory.Parent.FullName}
```

To move the file up one level & delete the \img folder (assuming it's empty):

```
gci A:\mozartBilder folder.jpg -recurse |
   move-item -Destination {$_.Directory.Parent.FullName}
gci A:\mozartBilder -recurse |
   ?{$_.PSChildName -match 'img'} | remove-item
```

Trying to combine move-item & remove-item in a single foreach-object resulted in error messages even though the file was moved & directory deleted, so I went with the above approach.

Comment: thanks, I tried it but I get an error `move-item : Cannot find path 'A:\folder.jpg' because it does not exist.
At line:3 char:8
+        move-item $_ $_.Directory.Parent
+        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (A:\folder.jpg:String) [Move-Item], ItemNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MoveItemCommand`

Comment: the command `gci A:\mozartBilder folder.jpg -recurse | select fullname` does give a full list of all items. the structure looks exactly like so: [link](https://pastebin.com/2hpANrTa)

Comment: Sorry about that. It worked in limited testing. Built a similar directory structure & got the same error. Answer now edited with updated code that should work.

Answer (score 0):

A nice, easy, way with GUI.

Download [Double Commander](https://doublecmd.sourceforge.io/); it's a twin pane file manager which is free, even for commercial use, and cross platform. You may soon find that you never visit the command line again.

The twin panes are great for move/copy/archive/unarchive/compare operations, not to mention FTP, file/directory compare, multi-file/directory rename, file search by name/contents (with wildcards/regex), etc.

You have two options here:

- Navigate to `A:\mozartBilder\Box 03 - Divertimenti, Serenades\CD02\img\` in the left pane and `A:\mozartBilder\Box 03 - Divertimenti, Serenades\CD02\` in the right pane

  - select all files in the source directory by using the keypad `plus` key, ***or*** by hitting Ctrl-A
  - press F6 to move all files and `enter` to select the destination

***OR***

- Navigate to `A:\mozartBilder\Box 03 - Divertimenti, Serenades\CD02\img\` in the left pane

  - select all files in the source directory by using the keypad `plus` key, ***or*** by hitting Ctrl-A
  - press F6 to move all files and type `..` (parent directory) for the destination.

Quod erat demonstrandum :-)

Since no answer is complete without an image ...

[image]

Please let us know how it works out (and take a good look at all of DC's features; I only scratched the surface above)

Comment: so there are 180 ...\img\folder.jpg items which have to be moved. Following your instructions just takes care of one of them. I want to move them up one level by an automated command, so that I don't have to repeat the task myself 180 times.

Comment: Oops!  Hmmm, perhaps the "multi rename" command? Failing that, a simple Python script. You might want to consider asking us for an app on [software recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: I don't want to rename folder.jpg, I want to move them one level up the directory-hierarchy

Comment: I was hoping (I haven't tried this), that you could give a path + file name as the search text & replace text.